# RDLC SubReports Exporting to Excel Are Ignored

Tags: .net, rdlc

I have a RDLC report which has a table, calling a subreport N times.  This works perfectly in the control viewer and when I export to PDF.  Yet when I export to Excel, I get the following error:

> Subreports within table/matrix cells
>   are ignored.

Does anyone know why this occurs only within the Excel export? And is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See MSDN forum link below...looks like this is not supported in 2000/2005, but there also seem to be some kludgey workarounds (nested lists).  A Microsoft moderator claims that reporting services 2008 will export everything.

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1520229&SiteID=1

Answer (score 0):

Drop the table control from rdlc and Put your main report data into matrix control and put your sub reports below to maix control. 
Run your report and export again.It will be solved.